# Doctrine collection altered by other fetch query

Tags: unit-testing, symfony1, doctrine, doctrine-query

I'm new to Unit testing in symfony, and i'ts being pretty annoying, since I experienced one problem, which took me 1 hour to identify.

Hopefully, you guys will know why this happens.

So I'm testing my "search" method :

```
class TadalistTable extends Doctrine_Table
{
  public function search($query, $user_id)
  {
     $q = $this->createQuery('t')
     ->leftJoin('t.Notes n')
     ->where('n.name LIKE ?', '%'.$query.'%')
     ->andWhere('t.user_id = ?', $user_id);
     return $q->execute();
  }
}
```

It works perfectly fine on my website, but when I test it like this :

```
//Create two notes, one called "Test Note" and one called "Test Note2" in the same list

//Start test :
$searchTest = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Tadalist')->search('Test', $user->getId());
$searchNote2 = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Tadalist')->search('noTe2', $user->getId());

$t->is(count($searchTest), 1, 'Searching "Test" returned 1 list');
$t->is(count($searchTest[0]->Notes), 2, 'Searching "Test" returned 2 notes');
$t->is(count($searchNote2), 1, 'Searching "noTe2" returned 1 list');
$t->is(count($searchNote2[0]->Notes), 1, 'Searching "noTe2" returned 1 note');
```

The second test fails :

```
ok 20 - Searching Test returned 1 list
not ok 21 - Searching Test returned 2 notes
# Failed test (./test/unit/Model/TadalistTest.php at line 90)
# got: 1
# expected: 2
ok 22 - Searching noTe2 returned 1 list
ok 23 - Searching noTe2 returned 1 note
```

But if I just change the order :

```
//Create two notes, one called "Test Note" and one called "Test Note2" in the same list

$searchTest = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Tadalist')->search('Test', $user->getId());
$t->is(count($searchTest), 1, 'Searching "Test" returned 1 list');
$t->is(count($searchTest[0]->Notes), 2, 'Searching "Test" returned 2 notes');

$searchNote2 = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Tadalist')->search('noTe2', $user->getId());
$t->is(count($searchNote2), 1, 'Searching "noTe2" returned 1 list');
$t->is(count($searchNote2[0]->Notes), 1, 'Searching "noTe2" returned 1 note');
```

It works :

```
ok 13 - Searching Test returned 1 list
ok 14 - Searching Test returned 2 notes
ok 15 - Searching noTe2 returned 1 list
ok 16 - Searching noTe2 returned 1 note
```

After debugging, I've seen that after the first query, the searchTest[0]->Notes contains the two "Note" objects I created (named "Test Note" and "Test Note2"), and after the second, it just contains "Test Note" ("Test Note2" seems to have been removed by the second query).

So I'm wondering why it's working like this, and if their's a way to fix it.

Any of you knows about this weird behavior ?

Comment: Very weird... I think you should debug further, to see when exactly the change happens. With a step-by-step debugger like XDebug it should be easy to know.

Comment: I don't have XDebug, I'll try it

Comment: You can use XDebug for step-by-step debugging with PDT, Netbean, vim, Notepad++ and more...

Answer (score 0):

Here's my hypothesis: in both queries you're getting the same *Tadalist* object (identified by the same primary key). Doctrine probably uses reference to the same object in both collections. Second query overwrites Notes returned by the first query.

**Note**: that's just a hypothesis. Please verify if it actually happens.